# GCP VM instance hosted Website showing connectino refused error message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to fix a website that is hosted on Google Cloud Platform using VM instance. The website is giving me a ***connection refused error*** message. I have checked that the firewall rules are set up and are provided to the VM instance. 
The VM external IP is static and the same IP is present on both cloud DNS and GoDaddy.

I'm also unable to SSH into the instance.

[The SSH screen is stuck here and is not loading any further](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQHEU.png)

I have given the necessary permissions to the instance and the user (Compute Admin, Compute Instance Admin (v1)), but still no luck.

As the instance is created from a custom image, so later, I tried creating another instance with the same config and I was able to SSH from it. So, please find some screenshots attached below if those could be of any help

[netstat -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax7UE.png)

[route -n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QezT.png)

[df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7mzS.png)

I am new to this so any help to fix the issue and get the website up and running would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Shutdown the instance. Resize the boot disk. Restart the instance. For most Linux versions, Google will resize the root file system automatically. I wrote an article that covers how this is done: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/

Answer (score 0):

If it worked at the second attempt (2nd Instance I mean), I suspect that the SSH service hasn't started properly. I would recommend you to check the [Serial Port Output](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output), and [Accessing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#enable_instance_access) into the Instance through the serial port in order to be able to troubleshoot it.

Note that you'll need a user to access through the serial port. If you don't have any user created, you will be able to do so using an [startup-script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Adrian, I looked into the [Serial Port Output](https://imgur.com/CXHvbQM) and 1 thing that I could infer was "WARNING [Errno 28] No space left on device" so I added another disk with 100 GB storage but that also didn't seem to help
I have also added some [custom metadata](https://imgur.com/42VhqN5) into the instance.
However, I am still not able to SSH into the instance or fix the website.

Comment: Did you followed this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) while resizing it?

Comment: Adrian is right. Seems like your disk is full so you can’t just create a larger disk. You need to make sure that you are following the process correctly as described in [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#inaccessible_instance).

Comment: This article may help for you to get into your Compute Engine if you are locked out because SSH won't start ... https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b